# Unaspected different result based on using sql variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, join

I do not understand the results of the queries...
The result change using different joins and declared variables or costants.

What's going on?

```
declare @inserted table
(id              int,
 tnumber         nvarchar(50),
 id_prod_inesito int
);

insert into @inserted
values
(41649,'0438492300',172400);

select pic.ID
      ,PIC.ID_PROD_INESITO
      ,pic.NUMERO_TELEFONO
      ,pic.IS_REQUESTED
      ,ins.*
      ,min(pic.id) over(partition by pic.numero_telefono) as min_id
from prod_ivr_call as pic
    inner join prod_inesito as pin
        on pic.ID_PROD_INESITO = pin.ID
    left join @inserted as ins
        on ins.ID_PROD_INESITO = pin.ID
where pic.is_requested = 0;
```

[image]

If I change the join in a inner join

```
select pic.ID
      ,PIC.ID_PROD_INESITO
      ,pic.NUMERO_TELEFONO
      ,pic.IS_REQUESTED
      ,ins.*
      ,min(pic.id) over(partition by pic.numero_telefono) as min_id
from prod_ivr_call as pic
    inner join prod_inesito as pin
        on pic.ID_PROD_INESITO = pin.ID
    join @inserted as ins
        on ins.ID_PROD_INESITO = pin.ID
where pic.is_requested = 0;
```

or

```
select pic.ID
      ,PIC.ID_PROD_INESITO
      ,pic.NUMERO_TELEFONO
      ,pic.IS_REQUESTED
      ,ins.*
      ,min(pic.id) over(partition by pic.numero_telefono) as min_id
from prod_ivr_call as pic
    inner join prod_inesito as pin
        on pic.ID_PROD_INESITO = pin.ID
    left join @inserted as ins
        on ins.ID_PROD_INESITO = pin.ID
where pic.is_requested = 0
      and ins.id is not null;
```

[image]

instead writing

```
select pic.ID
      ,PIC.ID_PROD_INESITO
      ,pic.NUMERO_TELEFONO
      ,pic.IS_REQUESTED
      ,ins.*
      ,min(pic.id) over(partition by pic.numero_telefono) as min_id
from prod_ivr_call as pic
    inner join prod_inesito as pin
        on pic.ID_PROD_INESITO = pin.ID
    left join @inserted as ins
        on ins.ID_PROD_INESITO = pin.ID
where pic.is_requested = 0
      and numero_telefono = '0438492300';
```

[image]

finally writing

```
select pic.ID
      ,PIC.ID_PROD_INESITO
      ,pic.NUMERO_TELEFONO
      ,pic.IS_REQUESTED
      ,ins.*
      ,min(pic.id) over(partition by pic.numero_telefono) as min_id
from prod_ivr_call as pic
    inner join prod_inesito as pin
        on pic.ID_PROD_INESITO = pin.ID
    left join @inserted as ins
        on ins.ID_PROD_INESITO = pin.ID
where pic.is_requested = 0
      and numero_telefono = ins.tnumber;
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand the change of values from the first two queries but why I have different values from the last two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it changes.

You are finding the `min` `prod_ivr_call.id` value from the list of values returned by your query, not the table as a whole.  By adding the additional filters that remove the non-matched values from this table (ie: where `@inserted.id` is `null`), the `min` value will be different.

What has happened here is that you have misunderstood how windowed functions work.

Comment: Thanks. Now is clear the defference from the first two queries, but why I have different results from the last two?

Comment: Because the first one only filters the `prod_ivr_call` table on the `numero_telefono` column, which returns all rows with that telephone number whereas the second query checks for an equality between `prod_ivr_call.numero_telefono` and `@inserted.tnumber`.  Because any equality against a `null` value returns `null`, the condition is not met, so you only get the row where there is a match in the '@inserted' table.